# Copying data with pictures from one -wokbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks. A source Workbook(1) and an Destination Workbook(2). 
I am copying all the Contents from 1 to 2. 
I have the  below code running for this. 
I have a small problem with the workbook. 
I have my source book with pictures in it , Like the picture below.

I have included the column to be copied in my code. but I don't get those pictures. Could someone tell me how I can copy these pictures with the contents  to my destination sheet, with the below code.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Val As Variant
Dim filename As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2").Range("A4:P1000").ClearContents
CopyCol = Split("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P", ",")
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LCell = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
LCC = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LCR = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set y = ThisWorkbook ' set ThisWorkbook object (where this code lies)
Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\Jenny\Raw data\Report.xlsx")
For Count = 0 To UBound(CopyCol)
Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "22:" & CopyCol(Count) & LCR)
If Count = 0 Then
Set CopyRange = temp
Else
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, temp)
End If
Next
CopyRange.Copy

y.Sheets("2").Range("A4").PasteSpecial
x.Close
End Sub
```

[image: The sample picture shows the model of the picture that looks in my original sheet. The sample picture contains two pictures but the original sheet contains 16 columns. With the present code I get the contents copied. I would like to copy the pitures also available in my column]Could someone suggest, how I can copy those picture with the content to the destination workbook.

Comment: If you copy  the **entire worksheet** to the destination, all the pictures will come with it.

Comment: But I don't need the columns after P. That's why I am mentioning the columns I need

Comment: Are this Pictures or Symbols?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
y.Sheets("2").Range("A4").PasteSpecial
```

try

```
y.Sheets("2").Paste y.Sheets("2").Range("A4")
```

Comment: I just encountered another problem. in my source sheet I have 580 rows with data and they start from column 22. But when I paste them I get only 91 data in my destination sheet

Comment: @Jenny - Is it Column 22 or Row 22?

Comment: sorry, it is row 22

Comment: @Jenny - Try writing `LCR = y.Cells(y.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` after `Set y = ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @Jenny - Debug and check what is the value of `LCR'.

Comment: I get an error , object does not support this property or method in the line lcr = y.Cells(y.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150079/discussion-between-mrig-and-jenny).